# retain text formatting from data input via vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to copy over values from one table to another in powerpoint with vba. The text involves a superscript "st", "nd", "rd", etc after the date. My code is:

```
slide3.Shapes(9).Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange = slide3.Shapes(2).Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
```

The values transfer over fine, but the "st", "nd"... become the same format as the rest of the characters.

I'd like for the superscript format to be copied as well.

Comment: I know this can be done if you iterate the characters in the textrange, and apply the desired source formatting that way.  I am not sure this can be done any other way, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this can be done without character iteration, but I know it can be done this way.  Create a subroutine which accepts the two `TextRange` objects as arguments, and then you can iterate each character.

Invoke it like:

```
CopyTextFormats slide3.Shapes(9).Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange, _
                   slide3.Shapes(2).Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
```

Here is the subroutine:

```
Sub CopyTextFormats(tRange1 As TextRange, tRange2 As TextRange)
Dim i As Long

'## "copy" the plain text from one table cell to the other
tRange2 = tRange1

'## Iterate the characters, in order to "copy" specific formatting properties:
For i = 1 To tRange1.Characters.Count

tRange2.Characters(i, 1).Font.Superscript = tRange1.Characters(i, 1).Font.Superscript
'### You can use this for other properties that you want to copy, too:
'
'tRange2.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = tRange1.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold
'tRange2.Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline = tRange1.Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline
'
'If you don't want to copy a property, just omit it from this function

Next

End Sub
```